# Storing day of week in PHPMyAdmin fields?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, phpmyadmin

I've got a database called **education1**, and all content is stored in the table **courses1**

These are the fields within courses:

```
class VARCHAR(255),
classinfo VARCHAR(255),
dayofweek VARCHAR(255)
```

However, I want to store the day of week in the DATE FORMAT, had a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date but that was for queries.

I'm wondering how to store the day of the week the classes run as named days, Monday - Friday.

I tried ENUM, but it wouldn't let me use the dash symbol to display:
Monday - Friday or Tuesday - Wednesday

Comment: It's better if you store an **index** of the day (0-6) or (1-7) and parse it in your PHP code, lighter and faster to retrieve.

Comment: Another option is to use an [`ENUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could do one of 2 things (note that those are recommended, you can do a whole bunch of other things.):

- Store an **index** of the day as `TINYINT` (0-6) or (1-7), and *parse* it on your PHP script to show as day names.
- Use an [**`ENUM`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html), for example:

  ```
  dayofweek ENUM('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday')
  ```

  That goes in the `CREATE TABLE` query.

As mentioned above, there are other things you could do, these will probably be the most efficient and effective for your problem.

Comment: I would definitely choose ENUM because it allows you to change the sort order in the database without changing your data or code. For example when "Sunday" comes after "Monday".

Comment: Indeed. Though I gave both solutions for that purpose, some would prefer an index because it is lighter then ENUM.

Comment: I currently had have big troubles when binding foreign-keys to ENUM-columns—which led to doubled data everywhere (one need to set up the same ENUM over and over, without a chance to change anything later); so I would stick to indices;

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use ENUM.

DO NOT use a varchar 255 field to hold a date or a string which is never longer than about 12 chars (depending on language).

If you want to hold a representation of a weekday in the database, then store it using a format you can use in a query to dereference a date value. MySQL has a function for this - [DAYOFWEEK(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

Then, if you must, maintain a table mapping these back to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use SMALLINT(1) and thats all. As i remember week got 7 days. So: 1-7 values. And read about normalization. I think where Class, there should be class_id.

So, this should look like:

***curses1***

id **|** class_id **|** dayofweek

***classes***

id **|** name **|** info

Query: `SELECT L.dayofweek, R.name, R.info FROM curses1 L LEFT JOIN clases R ON L.class_id = R.id`